# Why does $\int_{\theta}^{\infty}u(x)e^{-(x-\theta)}dx=-u(\theta) \implies Pr[u(X)=0]=1$?

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

I am trying to prove that a shifted expolential distribution is a complete set.

i.e.

$$X_1,...,X_n \sim_{iid} f_X(x;\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)}, 0<\theta<x$$ and if $E[u(X)]=0$ then
$$u(X) = 0$$.

The procedure I am taking is to first look at the expectation

$$\int_{\theta}^{\infty} u(x)e^{-(x-\theta)}dx=0$$

and take the derivative on both sides with respect to $\theta$.

I see that the result will be

$$\int_{\theta}^{\infty}u(x)e^{-(x-\theta)}dx=-u(\theta)$$

but I do not know how this leads to $u(X)=0$.

The notes that I am reading mentions that $Pr[u(X)=0]=1$ instead of $u(X)=0$ so I am thinking that I am missing something.

I would appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $E_{\theta}\left[u(X)\right]=\int_\theta^\infty u(x)e^{-(x-\theta)}\,dx=0$ (here $\theta$ need not be positive) is the same as $$\int_\theta^\infty u(x)e^{-x}\,dx=0\quad\forall\,\theta\in\mathbb R\tag{1}$$

Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $\theta$ one ends up with $$e^{-\theta}u(\theta)=0\quad\forall\,\theta$$

As $e^{-\theta}>0$ for any real $\theta$, the function $u(\cdot)$ must be identically zero.

In terms of random variables, this is equivalent as saying $u(X)=0$ with probability $1$.

This proves $u(X)$ is a complete statistic and the fact that the shifted exponential family is complete.

Comment: Oh, so it is quite straight forward from the result.  I have just one question, though.  Do you think there was a particular reason why my notes said $Pr[u(X)=0]=1$ instead of just saying $u(X)=0$?

Comment: @hyg17 because it is not true that $u(X)$ literally equals $0$. For instance, take $u(x)=1$ if $x=1$ and $0$ for all other $x$. Then $u(x)$ is piecewise-continuous and the integral evaluates to $0$, but $u(X)$ can equal both $1$ an $0$. However, the *probability* that it equals $1$ is zero (assuming an exponential distribution for $X$). Indeed, for a different distribution the probability might not be zero, for example a dirac distribution.

Comment: I see.  At my knowledge level it is quite difficult to fully understand the rigor, but now I at least know that it means something significant.  Thank you!

Comment: @hyg17 The phrase 'with probability one' or 'almost surely/almost everywhere' has a precise meaning in probability theory/measure theory. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere.

Comment: @StubbornAtom kitna rank aya tha ?